# How can I remove all spaces between two XML tags?

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I have a Perl script that I want to amend to remove spaces between two XML tags.

Example XML:

```
<TAG>
<TAG1><TAG2>abc 123 def 456 ... </TAG2></TAG1><TAG1><TAG2>xyz 987 ... </TAG>
```

I'd like to remove all occurrences of spaces between all `TAG2` tags. I tried the following:

```
$vModStrg =~ s/(<TAG2>(.*?)<\/TAG2>)/<TAG2>zzzzzz<\/TAG2>/g;
```

but this replaces the whole match with `zzzzz`. How can I tell Perl to only remove the spaces from the match for all the occurrences of `TAG2`?

Comment: Don't parse XML with regular expressions. Use a parser. This makes your problem absurdly easy. XML::Twig is good.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are a bad tool for this job, because parsing XML requires recursion. You can do that with newer versions of regex, but at best it leads to very complicated and hard to read regular expressions, and ones with edge cases where they'll break.

See: [Why it's not possible to use regex to parse HTML/XML: a formal explanation in layman's terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la)

So use a parser - to remove 'spaces between `<TAG2>` elements':

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig; 

#parse the data from our "DATA" filehandle. 
#you might want "parsefile('somefilename.xml')" instead. 
my $twig = XML::Twig -> parse ( \*DATA );

#iterate 'text' below "TAG2" anywhere in the document. 
foreach my $tag ( $twig -> get_xpath ('//TAG2/#TEXT') ) {
    #modify this tag. 
    $tag -> set_text($tag -> text =~ s/\s+//gr ); 
}
#set output options
$twig -> set_pretty_print('indented_a');
#print to STDOUT. You might want:
#print {$output_fh} $twig -> sprint; 
$twig -> print;

__DATA__
<root>
   <TAG2>words with spaces</TAG2>
   <TAG2>
       <child>wordswordswords more words
       </child>
   </TAG2>
   <TAG1>some more words with spaces</TAG1>
   <TAG2>something here
       <another_child att="fish" />
   </TAG2>
</root>
```

This outputs:

```
<root>
  <TAG2>wordswithspaces</TAG2>
  <TAG2>
    <child>wordswordswords more words
       </child>
  </TAG2>
  <TAG1>some more words with spaces</TAG1>
  <TAG2>somethinghere<another_child att="fish" /></TAG2>
</root>
```

So as you can see - correctly modifying text between `<TAG2>` elements, and leaving other stuff untouched. And for bonus points, it's at least as clear what it's doing as an equivalent regex would be!